# Removing spaces in a char array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to remove spaces from an array and rearrange the values of the array.

```
array[]="1  2 6    9  5";
```

I want the values of array like

```
array[]="12695"
```

Comment: Nulls and spaces are not the same thing. Which do you actually want to remove?

Comment: Seems like you want to remove spaces in the string.check [this](https://codescracker.com/c/program/c-program-remove-spaces-from-string.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that they are different. If they are different then i want to remove spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of ways to whip up a simple solution to remove spaces from a string. Here's a little example I came up with using pointer iteration:

```
void remove_spaces(char * str){
    char * back = str;
    do{
        if(*back != ' ')
            *str++ = *back;
    }while(*back++ != '\0');
}
```

This code uses two pointers to iterate across the given string. At each step of the loop, the `back` pointer is checked against the null character (to see if the end of the string has been reached) and incremented. In the body of the loop, the value from the back pointer is copied into the front pointer whenever `back` is not pointing to a `' '`. `str` is also incremented right after this copy from `*back` to `*str` is made, using the post-increment (`++`) operator.